# Dropbox - large files changing frequently

Tags: windows-7, ssd, dropbox

I am working on a project in which I am often changing a 2.5GB file (using my own software). The file is stored in my dropbox directory on an SSD drive. Usually writing the file is fast enough but occasionally it is 20x or 50x slower. It occurred to me that in periods where I make many changes in quick succession, dropbox could not reasonably keep up making backup copies of every version I create (like it certainly does with all my small files) unless it somehow deliberately caused a slowdown in how fast a new version of the file could be written.

So my question is - could dropbox be the cause of my slow file writing... (and if it isn't the cause, what does dropbox do if you have big files changing frequently?)

Comment: It's slow writing (saving) onto your internal SSD? I'm guessing it's not dropbox slowing it down, it should be mainly read-only anyway here, unless your SSD really slows down if writes are interrupted by reads... Why not turn dropbox off and see if it still happens?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have some sort of hybrid disk setup in which things are kinda "cached" by an SSD but with most space backed by a traditional HDD?

Comment: This could also possibly be caused by your antivirus software:  If Dropbox appears to sync files quickly at first, but then appears to be stuck at the last moment, it's possible your antivirus or system optimization application is interfering with the Dropbox application. This is a known issue with antivirus applications

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and add path that contains your file name. Start Capture just before you save the file, then Stop Capture after. See what processes are interacting with the file. Remember, that Dropbox has to chunk your 2.5GB into 4MB pieces and get a hash of each piece. That involves a lot of I/O. Still, that shouldn't delay your write times. Some process is getting involved earlier such as anti-malware or anti-virus like @Musselman LLC suggests. I have Cylance at work and it loves to cause performance delays on large files.